# Link/move documentation to tag for [android-databinding]

Tags: discussion, documentation

I hope this is the right place to ask.

Is there a way to link or maybe move the [Data Binding Library documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/111/data-binding-library#t=201704060946519237121) to the tag [android-databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-databinding)?
As of now, the tag page for `[android-databinding]` shows a proposal to create a new documentation. I think it would be useful to show that there are already examples available in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

All documentation related to Android should be in the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag. So [android-databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-databinding) should not have a separate documentation. If we would do that, the documentation would be fragmented across dozens of tags, and it would get very unclear where to find what documentation.

But you could edit the [android-databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-databinding) tag wiki and add a link to the [data binding topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/111/data-binding-library#t=201704061103306642304) of the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) docs.

Comment: I do not wish to create a seperate documentation, only to somehow show users that there already exists documentation (beside the tag wiki edit).

Comment: @Amylinn: If the [android-databinding] tag is created (and I hope it won't be) we can point the documentation to the [android] tag instead.

Comment: [android-databinding] is an existing tag, I put a link in my question - or.. what did you mean? Sorry, english isn't my native language :) Pointing the documentation to [android] would be great.